# Window onload function is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code :

I have used window onload function to populate ui elements but it is not working properly.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Regalo - Shop</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).on('load',function(){
    alert("OK");
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${itemList}">

            var name= '${item.desktopbrand}';
            var details='${item.details}';
            var id = '${item.desktopid}';
            var price = '${item.desktopid}';
            var catagory = '${item.catagory}';          

    var spanTag = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"> <div class="thumbnail"> <img data-src="img/Desktop/'+ id +'.jpg"> <div class="caption"><h3>'+ name+ '</h3> <p>'+ price+ '</div> </p> <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="details()">Show Details</button></p><p><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" onclick="addToCart()">Buy now</button></p></div></div></div>';
    $("#" + catagory).append(spanTag);
        </c:forEach>
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Gens Cooner</h1>
    <div id="gen" class="container"></div>
    <h1>Ladies Cooner</h1>
    <div id="lad" class="container"></div>
    <h1>Childrens Cooner</h1>
    <div id="chil" class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to find the issue but couldn't. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't try to debug JavaScript by looking at server side code.

Comment: Look at the JavaScript that your server side code outputs. Determine why it doesn't work. Then either just fix that, or determine why the server side code doesn't give you the output you think it should.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using your server-side code to generate HTML contents, rather than haxing in some JavaScript instead?

Comment: Agree with what @Quentin said but you could also try using `$(document).ready(function(){...`

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function(){ alert('Working!!'); }
```

Use above function and make sure you use only one `window.onload` function in a page